# Can I find out if user's web browser has stored an exception for my self-signed ssl certificate?

Tags: javascript, security, ssl, browser, https

Is it possible to find out, e.g. in javascript, if a browser has stored a security exception for a self-signed ssl certificate?

I want to provide a message to users telling them to expect the security warning and what the certificate details will be BEFORE they try to navigate to a page being served over https, but I only want to give that message to users who are going to get the security warning, i.e. users who have not stored the exception for my security certificate.
(The site is for a new non-profit unincorporated association so it may be difficult to get a CA certificate even if there were a budget for one.)

Comment: You generally can't access this sort of data from within the browser. Getting a domain-validated cert shouldn't be a problem, even for a non-profit unincorporated association, if you have a domain name for it.

Comment: there are some companies that provide free valid SSL certificates

Comment: Don't do this. You can get a free or almost free domain-validated certificate.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to provide a message to users telling them to expect the security warning and what the certificate details will be BEFORE they try to navigate to a page being served over https, but I only want to give that message to users who are going to get the security warning, i.e. users who have not stored the exception for my security certificate.

I would consider this a bad idea.
If you train users to believe such messages it will be easy for a man-in-the-middle attacker to just show a similar warning and then do a man-in-the-middle SSL attack with the attackers certificate.

> (The site is for a new non-profit unincorporated association so it may be difficult to get a CA certificate even if there were a budget for one.)

First, there are kind of free SSL certificates (they might not charge for the certificate, but for the revocation). Apart from that a simple certificate is not that expensive if you just compare it to the server costs or some cups of coffee. 
And if you really want to protect your users you should not use some kind of broken HTTPS but do it right.

> Is it possible to find out, e.g. in javascript, if a browser has stored a security exception for a self-signed ssl certificate?

While I think it is a bad idea to show such a warning the following technique can be used in similar scenarios, i.e to show the user that it needs to update its old software because it cannot accept newer certificates:

You can try to include a resource like an image from the https protected side. Modern browsers (I've tested with recent Chrome and Firefox) will not show a warning if the certificate for the resource failed but instead silently fail to load it. You can check with Javascript then if the resource got loaded (user has exception for certificate) or not (no exception).

Comment: That's a good point about the ease of a lure into a false sense of security. I've found I can get a cert from RapidSSL for $25 from certs4less though it seems that it may need some intermediate certs to work (RapidSSL own site is untrusted on my iPhone). Many thanks. :)